# Difference between increasing integer values of $C=x^2+y^2+z^2$

Tags: integers, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

Given are non-negative integer variables $x$, $y$ and $z$. I am trying to deduce the absolute difference between a certain value of $C=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and the very next smallest increase in $C$ possible.

I'd like to do this so I can (dis)prove the following:

- Whether small absolute differences occur less frequently at higher values of $C$
- Whether larger absolute differences start appearing at higher values of $C$

Perhaps I am missing something obvious but can a formula be deduced that (dis)proves this?

Comment: The difference between $n^2 + n^2 + n^2$ and $(n-1)^2+n^2+(n+1)^2$ is $2$ regardless of $n$.

Comment: Look up Legendre's three-square theorem to understand which integers can be represented as the sum of 3 squares.

Comment: @dxiv But some $3n^2+1$ can be represented as the sum of 3 squares. EG $n = 2, 3n^2 + 1 = 13 = 9 + 4 + 0 $.

Comment: @CalvinLin That's correct, and I did not mean to imply that $2$ was the smallest possible difference. Point was that it's a constant, which does not increase with $C=3n^2$.

Comment: @dxiv Not quite sure what you mean by "it's a constant". The difference is either 1 or 2, depending on whether $n+1$ can be written as the sum of 3 squares or not. (And for any 2 consecutive numbers, at least one of them can be written as the sum of 3 squares.)

Comment: @CalvinLin I meant this part of OP's question: "*see whether this absolute difference increases with higher values of C*".

Comment: @dxiv Do you mean when all three integers have the same value? Because in that case the difference does not always need to be $2$. E.g. if $n=2$ then $C=12$ and the very next smallest step is $C=13=3^2+2^2+0^2$

Comment: @Phy That's correct. My comment did not mean or imply that $2$ must be the *smallest* difference. Point was that you can find arbitrarily large triplets with the smallest difference $\,\color{red}{\le} 2\,$, so it is clearly not the case that "*this absolute difference increases with higher values of $C$*", which was part of your question.

Comment: @dxiv I now understand what you mean. I should have rephrased my question. Would these small difference occur less frequently at large integer values? And aside from that, would larger differences also start appearing at larger integer values?

Comment: @Phy OEIS [A004215](https://oeis.org/A004215) states that at least one out of any three consecutive positive integers can be written as a sum of $\,\le 3\,$ squares, though I don't see a reference to the source for that.

Comment: Perhaps not important but the answer is completely different if C must be a perfect square.  That’s the only “form” of this question that I can help with.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks, I understand now that the sum of three squares would *not* give any value coming out of the formula $4^a (8b+7)$ where $a$ and $b$ are independent integers. However, because of the 2 independent variables, I don't know how to use this formula to show whether the absolute difference increases or not at higher values of $C$. Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: @Phy The difference is either 1 or 2 infinitely often, and is only those values. It doesn't "increase at higher values". EG It is never 3.

Comment: @CalvinLin If the differences between increasing $C$ is either $1$ or $2$ in random order, doesn' this mean that the smallest possible difference between the outcomes of Legendre's formula $4^a(8b+7)$ is $2$?

Comment: The numbers of the form $ 4^a ( 8b+7)$ do not occur consecutively. You can show the by considering the values mod 8.

Comment: @CalvinLin It does seem to give consecutive numbers, e.g. $4^0 (8*13+7)=111$ and $4^2(8*0+7)=112$.  I think you forgot to consider the fact that numbers coming out of the formula with lower $a$ and higher $b$ can come close to numbers from higher $a$ and lower $b$'s. One would have to take all the possible combinations of $a$'s and $b$'s into account to see what numbers it can give within a certain chosen range.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. The remainders mod 8 are 0, 3, 7, so we could have consecutive values there. So, the values are 1 or 2 or 3 (likely infinitely often).

Comment: @CalvinLin I'm trying to grasp why this can be deduced so easily using the mod function.   Could you perhaps elaborate this in an answer to the OP?

Comment: @CalvinLin It seems that you are correct. Could you please explain how you have concluded the remainders of mod 8 being $0, 3, 7$ and deduce from that the differences being $1, 2, 3$?

Comment: @Phy Actually, the remainders are $0, 4, 7$ sorry. If $ a = 0$, then the remainder is $7$. If $ a = 1$, then the remainder is $ \equiv 4 $. If $ a = 2$, then the remainder is 0.   $\quad$ So if we have 2 consecutive terms $ 8n-1, 8n$ that each could be written as $ 4^a (8b+7)$, then the difference will be 3. It remains to show that this is always possible (which I believe it should be).

Comment: @CalvinLin Are you using $4^a \mod 8$? Shouldn't one be using $(\frac{n}{4^a}-7)\mod 8$ instead? Sorry but I don't get how $4^a \mod 8$ would give valid conclusions about the formula $4^a (8b+7)$.

Comment: If $ a \geq 2$, what is $ 4^a ( 8b+7)  \pmod{8}$? It is a multiple of 16.